# Power BI paginated report: can it refresh dataset automatically when datasource is changed modified?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a power BI dataset, and I was asked to create a paginated report that refresh automatically each month. The good thing here is that I will have an automatical design of the report page and data will be split in as much pages as the data has.

The thing is that the datasource will be in constant changes, cause it retrieves data from a data entry team. So, when this data source is modified, that will refresh automatically dataset in power bi service, but I don't know if that will be automatically refreshed in my paginated report.

I have asked microsoft regarding this issue, but it wasn't very clear to be honest and frankly, I haven't find a straight answer for this topic, that's why I'm writting to the community.

In conclusion, is it possible for the paginated report to be autorefreshed when datasource is modified? If not, how can I achieve this in other platforms or languages? Is there a way of making it in python so I can automate this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paginated reports fetch data every time they run.  They don't cache data.